# MS Word: How to display header on first page only?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, headers

I inherited a one-page MS Word doc with letterhead. In future, the content could run to two pages. How can I set up the header to appear on the first page only? I'm working in Word 2016.

First off, I had trouble finding where to set header properties.

Second, when I checked the box for "different first page" and deleted the header contents, the letterhead disappeared entirely.

Answer (score 2):

1. At least in my version (2016), the header tools only become visible in the ribbon after double-clicking somewhere in the header or footer area.
2. The problem was that the doc was too short.  Here's how I finally got it to work:

   - temporarily add enough carriage returns or dummy text so the doc reaches at least to a page and a half total.
   - copy the contents of the header and stick it somewhere in the document temporarily.
   - check the box for "different first page" (from the header tools).
   - don't panic if the header disappears from both pages -- just copy and paste it back into the header area in the first page and restore formatting (e.g. centering).
   - remove all the temporary stuff from the body.